# How do I apply multiple coupons to an account in Recurly?

Tags: php, api, coupon, recurly

[Recurly Create Subscription.](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-subscription) It doesn’t seem like they allow multiple coupons to be allowed added to the account during creation, but am I wrong? Or is there another way to add a coupon to the account subscription?

I already have multiple coupons setting in Recurly turned on, I'm just not sure how to apply them. I'm also using the PHP library if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out you can actually create subscription with multiple coupons at once. All you need to do is organize coupon codes into comma separated list.

Comment: I get an error when I do this!  Can you post how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the redeem subscription endpoint (rather than the create subscription endpoint) if you wish to apply multiple coupons

`<?php
$coupon = Recurly_Coupon::get('special');
$redemption = $coupon->redeemCoupon('1', 'USD');
?>`

More information [here](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/redeem-a-coupon-before-or-after-a-subscription)

Answer (score 0):

You should work with **Redeem a Coupon on an Account**

**Definition**

https://:subdomain.recurly.com/v2/coupons/:coupon_code/redeem

**PHP Examples**

```
<?php
$coupon = Recurly_Coupon::get('special');
$redemption = $coupon->redeemCoupon('1', 'USD');
?>
```

**Result Format**

```
 <redemption href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1/redemptions/316a4213e8fa9e97390aff4995bda9e6">
            <coupon href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/coupons/special"/>
            <account href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/accounts/1"/>
            <subscription href="https://your-subdomain.recurly.com/v2/subscriptions/315fbd7a25b04f1333ea9f4418994fb5"/>
            <uuid>316a4213e8fa9e97390aff4995bda9e6</uuid>
            <single_use type="boolean">false</single_use>
            <total_discounted_in_cents type="integer">0</total_discounted_in_cents>
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <state>active</state>
            <created_at type="datetime">2015-09-23T17:13:30Z</created_at>
          </redemption>
```